# QuickBooks java SOAP Web Connector structure

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, quickbooks

i have inherited a java app that integrates with desktop QB.  There's something in the structure of this whole setup i'm not understanding.  This is my first go with the QB api as a developer.

the QB Web Connector 2.2.0.71 is installed and functional.  I see the .qwc file and understand it, and it is loaded into the web connector.  There is an Application class that publishes an endpoint to the same URL as in the .qwc file and then starts a class named QBWebService.  this web service class implements com.intuit.developer.TroubleshootWebServiceFSSoap and has methods authenticate, sendRequestXML, etc.  Method sendRequestXML has the code i am testing and attempting to modify.  but, before i can do that i need to understand the XML going back and forth.

since i don't know what i don't know, if i'm asking the wrong questions, by all means, please say so.

is it correct, then, that the web connector (on schedule) launches the application class and calls the sendRequestXML method?

i was expecting to find a URL that i could send XML to with something like SOAPui in order to test the XML and examine the response, but that doesn't seem to be how this web service works.  is it possible to set it up this way?

perhaps i don't understand what the QB web connector application is doing.  what is the purpose of opening up the URL on localhost if it can't accept XML via POST?

thanks in advance for the help

--matt

Comment: SOAP is more complicated than todays REST, should use generated stub and not parse 'manually'

Answer (score 1):

> is it correct, then, that the web connector (on schedule) launches the application class and calls the sendRequestXML method?

Yes, that's correct.

> i was expecting to find a URL that i could send XML to with something like SOAPui in order to test the XML and examine the response

You can send requests to your SOAP service (e.g. you can call the `sendRequestXML` method for example).

You'll get back an XML response that (if you were the Web Connector) you would then relay to QuickBooks. QuickBooks would process the response, and then call the `receiveResponseXML` method to send the XML response back up to  your web service.

> perhaps i don't understand what the QB web connector application is doing.

It sounds like you're expecting QuickBooks to provide a SOAP endpoint, which you can then directly send XML requests to to query data directly from QuickBooks.

This is not really how the Web Connector works. The Web Connector sort of works "backwards".

Instead of connecting directly to QuickBooks, the Web Connector connects to *you* (your SOAP endpoint) and asks you "Hey, give me something to do!" (i.e. `send me the request XML you want to run against QuickBooks`). You then give it an XML request, which it runs against QuickBooks, gets the response, and then connects to you again and says "here's what QuickBooks responded to your request with" (i.e. `here you go, receive this response XML from QuickBooks`).

So the Web Connector essentially polls a SOAP endpoint you provide, asking you to give it XML requests to pass through to QuickBooks.

Longer explanation here:

http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview#About_the_QuickBooks_Web_Connector